# How to get data for different conditions in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[K_FS_GetFEEDMRPDetails] 
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Select 
        FT.FeedType,
        round(MR.rateperkg, 3) as rateperkg,
        round(MR.rateper50kg, 3)as rateper50kg 
    from 
        K_FS_FeedMrpDetails MR 
    inner join 
        k_FPS_FeedType FT on FT.sno = MR.feedtype 
    where 
        date = convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 101)
 END
```

This query shows today's inserted data. This is correct but I also want, if today didn't enter any data at that time I want to show last entered data. How can I do this? Please help me......

Comment: From What table the date columns in your where clause belong?

Comment: K_FS_FeedMrpDetails only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This code will select the latest inserted rows**

```
 SELECT FT.FeedType,
        Round( MR.rateperkg,3)As rateperkg,
        Round( MR.rateper50kg,3)As rateper50kg 
 FROM   K_FS_FeedMrpDetails MR
        inner join k_FPS_FeedType FT
            On FT.sno=MR.feedtype
 WHERE date in (SELECT TOP 1 date FROM K_FS_FeedMrpDetails ORDER BY date Desc )
```